# Obtaining a sum of all points of contact for users

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've currently got the following SQL Server statement which will be placed in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT [MessagerUserID], [MessagedUserID], sum(1) as CNT
FROM [dbo].[tmpMessaged] T1
group by [MessagerUserID], [MessagedUserID]
```

My output is as such:

```
MessagerUserID  MessagedUserID  CNT
4                      1          2
1                      4          2
3                      4          1
4                      5          1
```

What I need is a sum of all contact between user IDs.  So, something like this:

```
User1        User2        Contact
4              1             4
4              3             1
4              5             1
```

Doesn't really matter who is User1 and who is User2 (as far as which order they're in), I just need to combine lines as above to get the sum of all contact that 2 users have had with each other.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create 2 new columns, the bigger and smaller user id, and then do a group by + sum using them:

```
select
  User1,
  User2,
  sum(CNT)
from (
  SELECT 
    case when [MessagerUserID] > [MessagedUserID] 
      then [MessagerUserID] else [MessagedUserID] end as User1,
    case when [MessagerUserID] < [MessagedUserID] 
      then [MessagerUserID] else [MessagedUserID] end as User2,
    CNT
  FROM [dbo].[tmpMessaged] T1
) X
group by User1, User2
```

You can try this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cbd5a/2)

Comment: Note that the source table doesn't have any cnt column - it's computed using sum, but apart from that it's all correct, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Use case expressions to switch the values for MessagerUserID and MessagedUserID so that the MessagerUserID always has the lower value and then count and group by as you normally would. I'd wrap it in a common table expression for readability:

```
with cte as (
    select 
       case when MessagerUserID < MessagedUserID 
            then MessagerUserID else MessagedUserID end MessagerUserID, 
       case when MessagerUserID > MessagedUserID 
            then MessagerUserID else MessagedUserID end MessagedUserID
    from tmpMessaged
)

select MessagerUserID, MessagedUserID, count(*) as Contact 
from cte 
group by MessagerUserID, MessagedUserID
```